# How do I insert a list into another list?

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
A = [1,2,3]
B = [4,5,6]
```

Is there an elegant way to insert B into A at an arbitrary position?

Hypothetical output:

```
[1,4,5,6,2,3]
```

Obviously I could iterate through `B` and insert them one at a time, but I figured there was a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def insert(outer, inner, pos):
  outer[pos:pos] = inner
```

Answer (score 14):

```
A[1:1] = B
```

`A` will be  `[1, 4, 5, 6, 2, 3]`